# Slicing Dataframe column based on length of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the first 3 characters from strings in a Dataframe column where the length of the string is > 4

If else they should remain the same.

E.g

```
bloomberg_ticker_y

AIM9
DJEM9 # (should be M9)
FAM9
IXPM9 # (should be M9)
```

I can filter the strings by length:

```
merged['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str.len() > 4
```

and slice the strings:

```
merged['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str[-2:]
```

But not sure how to put this together and apply it to my dataframe

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bloomberg_ticker_y' : ['AIM9', 'DJEM9', 'FAM9', 'IXPM9']})

df['new'] = [x[-2:] if len(x)>4 else x for x in df['bloomberg_ticker_y']]
```

---

Output :

```
  bloomberg_ticker_y   new
0               AIM9  AIM9
1              DJEM9    M9
2               FAM9  FAM9
3              IXPM9    M9
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `numpy.where` to apply a condition to pick slices based on string length.

```
np.where(df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str.len() > 4, 
         df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str[3:], 
         df['bloomberg_ticker_y'])
# array(['AIM9', 'M9', 'FAM9', 'M9'], dtype=object)
```

```
df['bloomberg_ticker_sliced'] = (
   np.where(df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str.len() > 4, 
            df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str[3:], 
            df['bloomberg_ticker_y']))
df
  bloomberg_ticker_y bloomberg_ticker_sliced
0               AIM9                    AIM9
1              DJEM9                      M9
2               FAM9                    FAM9
3              IXPM9                      M9
```

---

If you fancy a vectorized `map` based solution, it is

```
df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].map(lambda x: x[3:] if len(x) > 4 else x)

0    AIM9
1      M9
2    FAM9
3      M9
Name: bloomberg_ticker_y, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `str[3:]` and `str.slice(start=3)` in terms speed or are these the same?

Comment: @Erfan They are the same! `.str[n:m]` is a shortcut for `.str.slice(start=n, end=m)`.

Comment: Thanks, was expecting that. Then there's no use case for `str.slice` imo, only point is it's more readable?

Comment: @Erfan I suppose. It's possible one came before the other, and both were preserved for backward compatibility. There could be various reasons to have many methods to do the same thing... :)

Answer (score 5):

Saw a quite big variety of answers, so decided to compare them in terms of speed:

```
# Create big size test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'bloomberg_ticker_y' : ['AIM9', 'DJEM9', 'FAM9', 'IXPM9']})
df = pd.concat([df]*100000)
df.shape

#Out
(400000, 1)
```

---

**CS95 #1 `np.where`**

```
%%timeit 
np.where(df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str.len() > 4, 
         df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].str[3:], 
         df['bloomberg_ticker_y'])
```

Result:

```
163 ms ± 12.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**CS95 #2 vectorized `map` based solution**

```
%%timeit 
df['bloomberg_ticker_y'].map(lambda x: x[3:] if len(x) > 4 else x)
```

Result:

```
86 ms ± 7.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**Yatu `DataFrame.mask`**

```
%%timeit
df.bloomberg_ticker_y.mask(df.bloomberg_ticker_y.str.len().gt(4), 
                           other=df.bloomberg_ticker_y.str[-2:])
```

Result:

```
187 ms ± 18.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

**Vlemaistre `list comprehension`**

```
%%timeit
[x[-2:] if len(x)>4 else x for x in df['bloomberg_ticker_y']]
```

Result:

```
84.8 ms ± 4.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**pault `str.replace` with `regex`**

```
%%timeit
df["bloomberg_ticker_y"].str.replace(r".{3,}(?=.{2}$)", "")
```

Result:

```
324 ms ± 17.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

**Cobra `DataFrame.apply`**

```
%%timeit
df.apply(lambda x: (x['bloomberg_ticker_y'][3:] if len(x['bloomberg_ticker_y']) > 4 else x['bloomberg_ticker_y']) , axis=1)
```

Result:

```
6.83 s ± 387 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

**Conclusion**

- Fastest method is `list comprehension` closely followed by vectorized `map` based solution.
- Slowest method is `DataFrame.apply` by far (as expected) followed by `str.replace` with `regex`

Comment: Interesting comparisons here! Did not think map with lambda would beat numpy, nor that list comprehensions would hold their performance for data this large.

Comment: Ye definitely, I expected numpy to win as well. I might start to use list comprehension more for conditional comparisons :) @cs95

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df['bloomberg_ticker_y'] = (df.bloomberg_ticker_y.mask(
                                      df.bloomberg_ticker_y.str.len().gt(4), 
                                      other=df.bloomberg_ticker_y.str[-2:]))

       bloomberg_ticker_y
0               AIM9
1                 M9
2               FAM9
3                 M9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'bloomberg_ticker_y' : ['AIM9', 'DJEM9', 'FAM9', 'IXPM9']})

df['bloomberg_ticker_y'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['bloomberg_ticker_y'][3:] if len(x['bloomberg_ticker_y']) > 4 else x['bloomberg_ticker_y']) , axis=1)
```

---

Output :

```
  bloomberg_ticker_y
0               AIM9
1                 M9
2               FAM9
3                 M9
```

Comment: This works! I upvote for the attempt. But for your learning curve, try to look at some of the answers above, which are considered best practice and will be much faster in terms of speed because of vectorization :). And btw, welcome StackOverflow :)

Comment: If you are interested, I included your answer in the speed comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837930/9081267).

Comment: @Erfan did you try to compare execution time with more 1000 executions? To be honest, I'm surprised that my solution is very slow, I think it's because the dataframe is small :)

Comment: See the lines on the top with `df = pd.concat([df]*100000)`. I create a test dataframe with 400 000 rows. There I do these tests on. Its a general knowledge that `.apply` is very slow compared to the vectorized solutions `pandas`/`numpy` provide. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584) about it. You only need apply in very edge case scenarios, not for this simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use regular expressions:

```
df["bloomberg_ticker_y"].str.replace(r".{3,}(?=.{2}$)", "")
#0    AIM9
#1      M9
#2    FAM9
#3      M9
```

The pattern means:

- `.{3,}`: Match 3 or more characters
- `(?=.{2}$)`: Positive look ahead for exactly 2 characters followed by the end of the string.